# Loading external JSON data into html

Tags: jquery, json

Im trying to make it so whenever I press my submit button, it will then fill out all of my "lorem ipsum" entries with the json data from another file. How do I go about making it so this works correctly?

This is my html code right now:

```
<!-- begin panel -->
            <div class="panel panel-inverse" data-sortable-id="table-basic-1">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <div class="panel-heading-btn">
                        <a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-xs btn-icon btn-circle btn-default" data-click="panel-expand"><i class="fa fa-expand"></i></a>
                    </div>
                    <h4 class="panel-title">New RTU FZB-1000 - FZB-1000</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <table class="table">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td><b>Status</b></td>
                                <td id="fld_status">Lorem ipsum dolor </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><b>Server Update</b></td>
                                <td id="fld_server_update">Lorem ipsum dolor </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel panel-inverse" data-sortable-id="table-basic-1">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <div class="panel-heading-btn">
                        <a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-xs btn-icon btn-circle btn-default" data-click="panel-expand"><i class="fa fa-expand"></i></a>
                    </div>
                    <h4 class="panel-title">Remote Terminal Unit</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <table class="table">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td><b>Signal Strength</b></td>
                                <td id="fld_signalstr">Lorem ipsum dolor </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><b>Main Power</b></td>
                                <td id="fld_power">Lorem ipsum dolor </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><b>Backup Battery</b></td>
                                <td id="fld_battery">Lorem ipsum dolor </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><b>Ambient Temperature</b></td>
                                <td id="fld_temp">Lorem ipsum dolor </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- end panel -->
            <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-4">
                    <input id="btn" type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary m-r-5"></input>
                </div>
```

This is my json code in test_json.json:

```
{
"fld_status": "Online",
"fld_server_update": "Friday, May, 19, 2017 10:33:53 AM Central Daylight Time",
"fld_signalstr": "42%",
"fld_power": "23.98 Volts",
"fld_battery": "7.538 Volts",
"fld_temp": "72 Degrees F",
}
```

Comment: Go to the jquery api and take a look at the getJson method.  Should give you some ideas.  http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJson/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering you've already got the `ID` and the `value`, you're pretty close! Assuming your JSON is stored in `var a` you should be able to use jQuery to find the element using the ID, and replace the text with the value! (After clicking submit)

```
$("#btn").click(function(){
  for (key in a) {
    var identifier = key;
    var value = a[key];
    $("#" + identifier).html(value);
  }
})
```

```js
var a = {
  "fld_status": "Online",
  "fld_server_update": "Friday, May, 19, 2017 10:33:53 AM Central Daylight Time",
  "fld_signalstr": "42%",
  "fld_power": "23.98 Volts",
  "fld_battery": "7.538 Volts",
  "fld_temp": "72 Degrees F",
};

$("#btn").click(function(){
  for (key in a) {
    var identifier = key;
    var value = a[key];
    $("#" + identifier).html(value);
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel panel-inverse" data-sortable-id="table-basic-1">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <div class="panel-heading-btn">
                        <a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-xs btn-icon btn-circle btn-default" data-click="panel-expand"><i class="fa fa-expand"></i></a>
                    </div>
                    <h4 class="panel-title">New RTU FZB-1000 - FZB-1000</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <table class="table">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td><b>Status</b></td>
                                <td id="fld_status">Lorem ipsum dolor </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><b>Server Update</b></td>
                                <td id="fld_server_update">Lorem ipsum dolor </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel panel-inverse" data-sortable-id="table-basic-1">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <div class="panel-heading-btn">
                        <a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-xs btn-icon btn-circle btn-default" data-click="panel-expand"><i class="fa fa-expand"></i></a>
                    </div>
                    <h4 class="panel-title">Remote Terminal Unit</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <table class="table">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td><b>Signal Strength</b></td>
                                <td id="fld_signalstr">Lorem ipsum dolor </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><b>Main Power</b></td>
                                <td id="fld_power">Lorem ipsum dolor </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><b>Backup Battery</b></td>
                                <td id="fld_battery">Lorem ipsum dolor </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><b>Ambient Temperature</b></td>
                                <td id="fld_temp">Lorem ipsum dolor </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- end panel -->
            <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-4">
                    <input id="btn" type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary m-r-5"></input>
                </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the assistance! I've been stuck on this for an hour or so! But not anymore!